# Need to display all rows of a large list in SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019

I have a large list (close to 4500 items) with many columns (about 100). My organization had SharePoint 2010 (on prem) until now and my client was happily using the datasheet view to display/bulk-edit rows in the list. Now, the organization is upgrading to SharePoint 2019 (on prem). I have tried using both the modern and classic modes, and the modern view seem to have problems with custom metadata fields for custom content types. Due to this, there is a good chance we would be asked to stick with the classic mode.

The view type in SP 2019 similar to Datasheet in SP 2010 is Quick Edit. In our Dev environment, I copied the large list and tried using the Quick Edit view but:

1. I find that the filtering options are much more limited in SP 2019 than they were in SP 2010. Is there a way to have the same custom filtering option in SP 2019 that is present out-of-box in SP 2010, especially for columns that have many different choices like "Project #"?
2. Is there a way to make SP 2019 show all rows of the list? So far, even in the Quick Edit view, SP 2019 displays only 30 rows at a time. This is a critical functionality for us and we do bulk-editing a lot of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. SharePoint filters pane are drastically updated from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2019, so OOTB there is no way of having the SharePoint 2010 filters pane in SharePoint 2019. To know more about the filters pane in SharePoint 2019, have a look at the below links,

   [What is the list and library filters pane?](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-is-the-list-and-library-filters-pane-293561ed-fb2e-4fb2-9a9f-8a21e299e323)

   [SharePoint filters pane updates](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/sharepoint-filters-pane-updates-filtering-and-metadata/ba-p/74162)
2. To increase the items in your quick edit view, modify your view and under "Item Limit" --> specify the no of items to be displayed in the list view and click OK

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We have had some difficulty saving managed metdata values in custom content types for documents when using the Modern mode. The filter pane is available only in the Modern mode so I will set the list to use the Modern mode and use the Classic mode for libraries.

Comment: Yeah. That will be a good idea.

Comment: If you find my answer useful upvote it and Mark it as answer, so that it will help others too

Comment: Ok so I was able to use the Filter pane in Modern experience to filter on a column that has a lot of different values. I had to pin the column to the filter pane as it was not being shown by default. The filtering successfully reduces the items displayed based on the filter, but I can do this only in non-editing mode. When I switch to Quick Edit mode, the filter is taken off and I am back to seeing all rows again. Filtering pane is not displayed in Quick Edit mode.

Comment: Karthik, I upvoted the response, but I do not have enough and the feedback was recorded, but I do not have more than 15 reputation so the up-vote would not be displayed publicly. Just FYI...

Comment: There you go, Now you have more than 15 reputation.

Comment: Filter pane is edit mode is very limited, that's how Microsoft has designed it. OOTB there is no way to alter it.

Comment: if you find my answer useful, kindly upvote and accept it as answer, so that it will help others too.